# Grails Sql executeUpdate with array as parameter

Tags: grails

I have this statement:

```
sql.executeUpdate("UPDATE outbound_message set acknowledged = true, acknowledged_date = NOW(), acknowledged_from = '" + userNameToUse + "'  where id in(" + msgList + ") and acknowledged = false")
```

msgList is a string like 2,4,5 containing the ids.

How can I make this as a prepared statement?

I tried:

```
long[] test = [1,2]
sql.executeUpdate("UPDATE outbound_message set acknowledged = true, acknowledged_date = NOW(), acknowledged_from = :user  where id in(:list) and acknowledged = false", [user:userNameToUse, list:test])
```

I get this exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How can I perform a IN() with a prepared statement?

Comment: What is the column type of your `id` column?

Comment: The column type in Postgres is BIGINT